# How can I pass field labels to yup schema?

Tags: formik, yup

I find myself repeating myself passing field labels to both yup schema and fields on formik form:

```
var schema = Yup.object({ foo: Yup.string().required().label("First name") });
...
<Formik validationSchema={schema} ...>
    <TextField name="firstName" label="First name"/>
</Formik>
```

wouldn't it be marvelous if I could register field metadata with formik and then have that metadata avilable to Yup somehow.
E.g. `validationSchema` attribute accepts a function. If this field metadata were to be avaliable as an argument to validationSchema - I can then build the schema with those labels.

Another approach is to declare the labels in an object, and then let both yup schema and my fields look it up from there (via a custom context, for example).

But there could be a simpler approach I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order calling the method:
instead of `foo: Yup.string().required().label("First name")` you need to use `foo: Yup.string().label("First name").required()`